# How can I change google map type with button click?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-directive

I made a directive for google map, that allow pass in mapType and address value:

```
.directive('map', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div></div>',
    scope: {
        'address': "@",
        'mapType': "@"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(scope, attrs);
        var geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geoCoder.geocode(
            {'address': scope.address},
            function(result, status){
                console.log(result, status);
                if(status==="OK"){
                    map.setCenter(result[0].geometry.location);
                    marker.setPosition(result[0].geometry.location);
                }
            }
        );
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: eval(scope.mapType),
            draggable: false
        };
        if(scope.mapType === undefined || scope.mapType === ""){
           mapOptions.mapTypeId = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP; 
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(attrs.id), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
        })
    }
  };
})
```

I also made a controller to control what map type I am going to pass in:

```
$scope.mapModules = [
    {
        text: "街道地图",
        value: "google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP"
    },
    {
        text: "鸟瞰地图",
        value: "google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE"
    }
];

$scope.selected = $scope.mapModules[0];
$scope.mapType = $scope.mapModules[0].value;

$scope.select = function(item){
    console.log(item);
    $scope.selected = item;
    $scope.mapType = item.value;
};
```

And that is the view layer to see the map:

```
<div class="row noPadding">
    <div ng-click="select(option)" class="col textCenter mapOption" ng-class="{'mapOptionActived': option == selected}" ng-repeat="option in mapModules">
          {{option.text}}
    </div>
</div>
<map map-type="{{mapType}}" id="schoolMap" style="height: 200px; width:100%" address="2140 w 41st Vancouver, BC"></map>
```

Everything works fine with first load the page, but when I click on the map module buttons, the map type doesn't change. So I am looking for solution that allow user can change map type when they click on the option buttons.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
var mapType = "ROADMAP";
map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId[mapType]);
```